# How to get data from table one based on ignoring data present in table 2 with combination of two columns

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables 
TABLE1 with two columns Col1 and Col2

```
Col1|Col2

A|1

A|2 

A|3

B|1

B|2

B|3

C|1

C|2

C|3
```

TABLE 2 with two columns Col1 and Col2

```
Col1|Col2

A|1

B|2

B|3
```

I want output as data of first table with ignoring data from second table. The data in TABLE1 is in combination of two columns Col1 and Col2

Output

```
Col1|Col2

A|2 

A|3

B|1

C|1

C|2

C|3
```

I have tried some solutions

```
SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM  Table1 t1
 inner join Table2 t2 on
 t1.Col1 <> (t2.Col1)
 and
 t1.Col2 <> (t2.Col2)
```

Also, I tried left join and extract but not got the correct solution for it.
 Could someone please provide any solution for the above query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.Col1, t1.Col2 
FROM  Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on
t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 
WHERE t2.Col1 IS NULL
```

You do a left join so you take everything from table1 and check that you get no hit on table2 by asking if you get NULL

Comment: You're welcome. This query might become a bit heavy when working with big data though

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select col1 + ' ' + cast(col2 as varchar) as fullname from @tb1 
where col1 + ' ' + cast(col2 as varchar) not in (select col1 + ' ' + cast(col2 as varchar) from @tb2)
```

Or

```
select col1,col2 from @tb1
where col1 + ' ' + cast(col2 as varchar) not in (select col1 + ' ' + cast(col2 as varchar) from @tb2)
```

Output

```
A 2
A 3
B 1
C 1
C 2
C 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Not Exists` to ignore same data present in another table.

```
SELECT T1.Col1, T1.Col2
FROM Table1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1/0 FROM Table2 T2 WHERE T2.Col1 = T1.Col1 AND T2.Col2 = T1.Col2)
```